# How to have physical location using google map api

Tags: google-maps, pug

I am relatively new to web development. I am trying to extract a physical location from the longitude and latitude using google map (i think google.map would be right for this). I have already written this code in JADE which gives me lat and long. How can i use this value to see the exact physical location. Thanks !

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
console.log('Geolocation is supported!');
var startPos;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  startPos = position;
  jQuery("#location_latitude").append(startPos.coords.latitude);
  jQuery("#location_longitude").append(startPos.coords.longitude);
  console.log(startPos.coords.latitude);
  console.log(startPos.coords.longitude);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A am sure you will find solution looking in the source:
http://html5demos.com/geo

You have to create the map and then locate a marker on it.